# Pepper Grass (not Lepidium virginicum)

Tags: identification

I'd like to know what a plant is that we refer to as "pepper grass" (but it's not *Lepidium virginicum*).

The plant looks like chive, but the small white bulb smells clearly of black pepper and not at all like onion.

What are likely candidates for this plant? If the description is not too vague, is it likely that it's edible?

Observed in coastal Texas growing in a lawn of San Augustine grass. Mowing prevented any chance of flowering so no blooms were observed. Photograph unavailable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plant could be Java grass/nut grass, *Cyperus rotundus*. I don't often use Wikipedia as a reference, but [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyperus_rotundus) gives a great description of the plant, complete with photos.

Some quotes from the article:

> Young plants initially form white, fleshy rhizomes, up to 25 mm (1.0 in) in dimension, in chains. Some rhizomes grow upward in the soil, then form a bulb-like structure from which new shoots and roots grow, and from the new roots, new rhizomes grow.

The "bulb-like structure" seems to be a good match for the small white bulb mentioned in your description.

> A sesquiterpene, rotundone, so called because it was originally extracted from the tuber of this plant, is responsible for the spicy aroma of black pepper and the peppery taste of certain Australian Shiraz wines.

Also note that the plant is a sedge, so it will have "edges" along the stem (it's triangular in shape). This is an easy ID marker if you have access to the plant.

If my ID is correct, then the plant is edible (and apparently will help prevent tooth decay, as noted in the linked article), but do **not** rely on my ID to determine edibility!

Comment: Bingo! I had forgotten the common name "nut grass". Your warning is noted.